# Same dimension feel no matter what FOV

Tags: unity, camera, first-person-shooter, frustum

Does anyone know a formula, way, ... to make a FPS player feel like an object has the same size on different FOVs (given that it's at the same distance of the player, of course)? I know that this can't be done perfectly, because of the distortion various FOVs cause and the position of the object (near the edges of the FOV = more distortion).
Let's ignore these distortions, and aim for a same size feel for objects that are directly in front of the player (so in the exact center of the FOV).

To clarify things a bit further: I want 1 object in my game to have the same scale feel on different FOVs, not my entire game world.

I've tried giving it a percentage of the frustrum height, but that doesn't seem to give me consistent results.

Note: I'm using vertical field of view in my game.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is [Dolly Zoom](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/DollyZoom.html).

Answer (score 0):

If the suggested dolly zoom is not what you are after, you could try this - not sure how well it'll work, though, this is pretty much of the top of my head. Store the initial view frustum height (`h0`) in a variable, and then when it changes (`h1`) compute the scaling factor `s = h1/h0`, and then uniformly scale your target object by `s`.

Now, if the FOV change is extreme, the distortion you mentioned may become a bit too pronounced; you could then experiment with dynamically modifying `s` to compensate - by making `s` larger or smaller; just multiply it with a floating point number that's around 1.0 (slightly higher or lower) and see what works best.

Once you have the values that work (say, `cMin` and `cMax`), you can use linear interpolation for that multiplier. For that, you'll need an interpolation parameter `t` that goes from 0 to 1 (0 will map to `cMin`, and 1 will map to `cMax` - think of it like a slider of some kind). So, you calculate your compensation factor like this:

```
c = (1-t)*cMin + t*cMax
```

To get `t`, you can use either the FOV angle or the view frustum height. Again, find some minimum value and a maximum value (say, `hMin` and `hMax`), and do:

```
t = (h - hMin) / (hMax - hMin)    // where h is the current value
```

This will produce `0` when `h == hMin` and `1` when `h == hMax`.

Finally, you calculate the scale:

```
sFinal = c * s         // or
sFinal = c * h1/h0
```